# iptables or nginx deny for ip blocking?

Tags: nginx, iptables

We use nginx as a loadbalancer and would like to:

- black-, white-list select IP ranges
- throttle requests coming from another set of IP ranges

...sourcing IP ranges from our internal list as well as places like [SpamHous](http://www.spamhaus.org/). Looks like this can be implemented using:
 1. iptables 
 2. nginx's [HttpAccessModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule).

Looking for advice on pro's and cons of each approach... So far, IMO nginx approach looks a bit more flexible (can create URI-based rules) but I am wondering whether iptables will perform better in case of a denial-of-service attempt by a blacklisted IP. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an either/or situation.

iptables will probably be more efficient, but as you mention, Nginx is a bit more flexible. Since I assume you won't need the flexibility for the blacklist, but might for the throttling,  Use iptables to blacklist, and use Nginx to throttle.